# What is % in format specifiers?

Tags: c

What is the proper name for the `%` operator in any format specifier? Like what does `%` in `%d` stand for? I have searched over the internet to help me figure out the solution but unable to find any. Any help?

Comment: *Have searched over the internet to help me figure out the solution but unable to find any.* - No you didn't

Comment: This is explained in every reference of `printf` out there.  http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/

Comment: It doesn't really stand for anything. It was chosen somewhat arbitrarily, though probably based on not needing to print it out as itself very often (though if/when you need to print one out, you can use `%%` in a format string to do that).

Comment: it defines that the next character will be identifying a format specifier

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can learn something from this **[TOPIC](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/159593/why-was-the-percent-sign-chosen-as-the-format-specifier-for-the-printf-famil)**.

Please find time to read and understand.

Answer (score 0):

% means, the character after % is the place holder and will be replaced by the respective argument.

Answer (score 0):

The character % does not have a special name other than "the character %".  It is not a C operator in the context of a format, but is simply a character used by 2 family of functions, as they read the format, to introduced a *conversion specification*.

Pulling verbiage from the C spec...

For both the `printf()` and `scanf()` family of functions there is a *format*.

The *format* is composed of zero or more *directives*.
1) one or more white-space characters  (scanf)
2) characters (not %)
3) *conversion specifications*

Each *conversion specification* is introduced by the character %.